# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'topic'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I know that the **"guild.text_channels.topic"** is incorrect as I've had problems with it in the past, and still have not found a solution. Basically, it's supposed to check all **channel topics** (Descriptions) to see if any of them contain **S|JoinMember**. The error with my code is shown below:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'topic'

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild = member.guild
    if "S|JoinMessage" in guild.text_channels.topic if guild.text_channels.topic else "":
        await channel.send("Welcome!")
```

Any ideas on what could solve or simplify this?

Comment: I explained this to you, it is a list of text channels. You access an element which is a `TextChannel` object, then you can access its `topic` attribute. If you want to check all the text channels, use a for loop. Learn OOP and python or some other programming language before you jump in to making a discord bot.

Comment: Dude, I'm just wanting some help. I can do other things in my bot, but I'm tryna help some others out with new features and I'm stuck

Comment: Use `for channel in guild.text_channels: if "S|JoinMessage" in channel.topic`

Comment: I tried implementing this, but it didn't work. I've tried using that, adding a colon, adding the 2nd part on the next line, and all kinds of stuff. None of them work, with the closest being on 2 lines which gives the error: `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`

Comment: I tried changing it to `for channel in guild.text_channels and "S|JoinMessage" in channel.topic:` which gave the the error: `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`

Comment: If you're still struggling with this it looks like you are still relatively new to Python. I suggest reading up on some documentation or doing some tutorials.

Comment: @ShinyDragon96 If you're getting the `NoneType` error again, please refer to one of your previous posts where a solution was provided to address this error.

Answer (score -2):

`guild = member.guild` will return `None` since the `Member` object does **not** have the attribute `guild`.

I don't think there is a work-around for this as the `on_member_join()` event only allows one parameter (`member`).

Instead, if you just wish to welcome the member, why not just send them a DM?

```py
async def on_member_join(member):
    dm_channel = await member.create_dm()  # creates DM channel
    await dm_channel.send("Welcome!")  # sends message
```

Also, if you are quite new to Python and discord.py, you would benefit from reading some documentation/tutorials:

- You should definitely read the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) thoroughly as it covers all of the language.
- The [discord.py API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is a good place to learn the basics of discord.py; it is very complete and helpful.

Comment: [`Member.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.guild). Also, if an object does not have a specific attribute, attempting to access it will raise an `AttributeError`; it will not return `None`.